# Why does -Wparentheses raise a warning if unnecessary parentheses are absent around assignment used as truth value in an if statement?

Tags: c++, c++17, compiler-warnings

`-Wparentheses` is giving me a warning on the following snippet:

```
long n = -1;
bool asking = true;
do
{
  ask_into("Enter the order of this Bezier curve (# of points):", n);
  if (asking = n <= 0) // <-- WARNING: "suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"
  {
    std::cout << "Please enter a number > 0.\n";
  }
}
while (asking);
```

The warning goes away if I change the problematic line to this:

```
if ((asking = n <=0)) // warning gone, but why the double parentheses?
```

Is there any rationale for the seemingly unnecessary parentheses around the assignment statement or is this just making sure I didn't intend to use `==` instead? Is there a more explicit preferred syntax requiring the parentheses that satisfies this warning without splitting the assignment statement from the conditional?

If it's any help the compiler I'm using is MSYS2 mingw-w64 g++ 12.2.0

Comment: It's making sure you didn't intend to use `==` instead.

Comment: The extra parens turns it into an expression.  That expression evaluation satisfies the compiler for not being an assignment in the `if` expression (because it is an assignment in a sub-expression).

Comment: @Eljay, it is an expression with or without the extra parentheses.  `=` is a binary operator.  Evaluation of `=` expressions produces a value.  That's why the extra parentheses are *optional*, not required.

Comment: Same for `==`, by the way.

Comment: it's close and does tell me how to suppress the warning, but the answer provided by @user17732522 really explains the reasoning for the extra parentheses to suppress the warning, that's what I was curious about, but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the intended behavior.

Part of the `-Wparentheses` functionality is to warn if an assignment expression is used as a condition, but only if directly. Extra parentheses around the assignment will make the warning ignore the condition.

The point of it is to make sure that you didn't accidentally write `=` instead of `==`, which is a common mistake while `==` is used much more than `=` in such a context.

Because you wouldn't normally add the unnecessary parentheses around the expression, if you *did* add them, then it is assumed to be a hint that you *really* thought about it and meant to write it that way, so that a warning shouldn't be produced.

There is no functional difference between having and not having the extra parentheses.